# Adding meta tags is not working in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I want to add meta tags in my angular component but nothing worked yet. Here is code lines I added/tried.

```
    import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';


    constructor(private meta: Meta) { 
    }

    ngOnInit() {
     //Adding tags
    this.meta.addTags([
      { name: 'description', content: 'Dynamic Hello Angular' }
    ], true);

     //Tried this too - Updating
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: 'Dynamic Hello Angular Lovers description!' }); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine according to the [docs](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta#description) and this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-meta-tags). I'd try to look for the source of the problem somewhere else.
I know it may sound banal, but are you sure, that the code got executed?

If it gets executed, can you use the other methods of the Meta api? (`get` or `remove`)